# How to make a BLE connection that is connected using service to use across the activities without stopping the service or disconnecting ble?

Tags: android, android-service, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-ble

I have 3 components.

1. **Activity1**  has button for connecting and disconnecting the BLE Connection
2. **Activity2**  Needs to Get the data from the BLE Device.
3. **Service**  All the connection logic (like getRemoteDevice(),connectGatt etc.,) belongs to service.

**Activity1** is connecting to BLE Device by binding the service.

```
Intent gattServiceIntent = new Intent(mContext,BleService.class);//In Activity1 context
bindService(gattServiceIntent, mServiceConnection,BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

and makes connection to ble device as soon as button is pressed.

Now when I move from **Activity1** to **Activity2** I am unbinding the service in **Activity1**.

```
mContext.unbindService(mServiceConnection);//In Activity1 context
```

Now How do I use the existing BLE Device connection in **Activity2** ?

**My temporary Solution:**

I am ***re Connecting*** the BLE Device again when moving to **Activity2** by new service instance binded to it from **Activity2** context. (Which I don't want.)

In **Activity2** I am checking whether my service is already running if not running then I am binding the service again from **Activity2** Context.

```
if(!isMyServiceRunning(BleWrapper.class)){
    Intent wrapperServiceIntent = new Intent(mContext,BleWrapper.class);    
    bindService(wrapperServiceIntent,mBLEWrapperServiceConnection,BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }else{
        Log.w(LOGTAG, "Service already connected. In onCreate");
    }
```

trigger the connection in onServiceConnected() under ServiceConnection callback

```
@Override
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName,IBinder service)     {
        
    mBluetoothLeService = ((BleWrapper.LocalBinder) service).getService();

    if (!mBluetoothLeService.initialize()) {
        showAlertDialog(getString(R.string.ble_not_supported_on_this_device));
    }else {
        mBluetoothLeService = BleWrapper.getInstance();
    }
 mBluetoothLeService.connect(/*address from shared preference*/); //Reconnecting to the same device using address stored in Shared pref
}
```

For Checking whether my service is running or not

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

But the function **isMyServiceRunning()** always returns false. meaning the service gets disconnected when moving from **Activity1** to **Activity2**

Any Solution for persisting the ble device connection across the activities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a LocalBinder(extends Binder) in your Service class. From Activity #1, you can start the service and also use bindservice to access the binder object and call unbindservice to disconnect from service. From Activity #2, you can simply call bindservice again to access the binder object as service is still running. This way you can keep the service running always and access the connected bluetooth objects. Refer the example from below link.

[bound service example](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)