# Accessing object in a background service from a class in android

Tags: android, bluetooth

Does anyone know how I can access an object that is in a background service from a class?

**The situation**
I am making a smartwatch, and in the app there is a background service to update it over bluetooth. When the app GUI is open, I want to be able change settings so they would get sent over bluetooth. The problem with this is, the background service creates an object called "blueHandler" of type "BluetoothHandler" (Which I wrote) which is not accessible from from the activity. I would also need to use the methods that are in "BluetoothHandler".

If anyone has any ideas, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If your service runs independent of your activity, then you can implement LocalBinder class and expose the BluetoothHandler as the binder object in your service. From activity you simply bind to the service using bindservice api call which will return the BluetoothHandler object. Using this you can invoke the methods you needed to interact with the smart watch.

Similar question is answered here. 
[How to connect to background service from different activities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33582305/950933)